# Iterate backwards and forwards over two lists at the same time in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have two lists:

```
list1 = [2,1,0]
list2 = [0,1,2]
```

I have tried this one.

```
for i,j in zip(list1,list2):
    print (i,j) //This prints out 2 0, 1 1 and 0 2
```

But I want to print out 2 2, 1 1 and 0 0. So I have to loop the second loop backwards while I loop the first one forwards. I know how to do each of these in separate `for loop`, but I cannot figure out how to do this in one single `for loop`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#reversed) function.

```
for i, j in zip(list1, reversed(list2):
    print(i, j)
```

Alternatively, depending on the data type, you can use fancy [slicing](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#slice). This generally works on data types that implement slicing (e.g. lists, tuples, numpy arrays), but won't work on a lot of other iterators.

```
for i, j in zip(list1, list2[::-1]):
    print(i, j)
```

The `list2[::-1]` slice means to slice the entire list with an increment of -1, which means that it will move backward through the list instead of forwards.

Comment: Depending on how the iterator implements `__reversed__`, using `reversed` can be more efficient. `list2[::-1]` has to actually generate a new list object to pass as the argument to `zip`.

Comment: @chepner Yea, that depends on the data type too. For example, `a[::-1]` makes a copy if `a` is a list, but doesn't make a copy if `a` is a numpy array. But I also agree that if you just want to iterate over something `reversed` is the way to go, especially because it makes the meaning more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option, which is very basic, but may get the job done:

```
for i,j in enumerate(list1):
    print j, list2[-i-1]
```

This will work as expected under the assumption both lists are the same length, otherwise, it will simply iterate for the number of elements in the first list.